# Compute the value of the Legendre Symbol

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The Legendre symbol that must be computed is (59/619). I changed it to -(619/59) later to -(29/59), then to -(59/29) finally -(1/29) by reciprocity and remainder rules.

At the last step I'm confused after -(1/29) because I do (-1)^ ((29-1)/2 )and it becomes (-1)^14 which is +1, but it seems that the answer is - 1.

Not sure how the answer was arrived. Thanks

Comment: $59\equiv 1\pmod{29}$ and $(1/29)=1$ since $1$ is always a quadratic residue.

Comment: $-(1/29)$ isn't the same as $(-1/29)$.

Comment: Do remember that $$\left(\frac{59}{619}\right) \equiv 59^{309} \pmod{619}.$$ That's laborious, of course, but if you have any doubt about the answer, that's one way to check it.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\left( \frac{59}{619} \right) &= -\left( \frac{619}{59} \right) & \text{(Quadratic Reciprocity, } 619 \equiv 3 \pmod{4})\\
&= -\left( \frac{29}{59} \right) \\
&= \left( \frac{59}{29} \right) &\text{(Quadratic Reciprocity, } 59 \equiv 3 \pmod{4})\\
&= \left( \frac{1}{29} \right) \\
&= 1 & \text{(Since  } 29 \equiv 1 \pmod{4})
\end{align*}
$$  $$